# How to create url for multiple files in react image uploader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, redux, upload

I'm creating a React app that works as a drag and drop image uploader. I'm having trouble creating URL for images if multiple images are dragged and dropped since I have to store URL and other image info to database in order to get them and display thumbnails on other page.  `URL.createObjectURL(image)` works for creating a thumbnail but the URL that I'm getting cannot be displayed on another page as an image. I tried using `FileReader()` but reducer returns a value before every image URL is created.

Here is the code:

```
case actionTypes.IMAGE:
        action.event.preventDefault();
        const acceptedImages = [...action.event.dataTransfer.files];        

        const modifiedImages = [];

        acceptedImages.forEach(async (image) => {
            if(image.type.startsWith('image/')) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                    modifiedImages.push(Object.assign(image, {
                        preview: reader.result
                    }));
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
            } else {
                alert('File type not supported!');
            }
        });

        return {
            ...state,
            images: [...state.images, ...modifiedImages]
        }
```

For this I'm using `onDrop` event which dispatches a function of type IMAGE.
I would be so thankful if anybody could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this

```
const getImageURL = (image) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(image.type.startsWith('image/')) {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve(Object.assign(image, {
          preview: reader.result
        }))
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(image)
    }
  })
}

const YourFunction = async (action) => {
  // your code
  const acceptedImages = [...action.event.dataTransfer.files];  
  const modifiedImages = [];

  acceptedImages.forEach((image) => {
    const result = await getImageURL(image)
    modifiedImages.push(result)
  })

  return {
    ...state,
    images: [...state.images, ...modifiedImages]
  }
}
```